# Having problems attaching files to multiple items using powershell

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, powershell

Im having issues attaching files to multiple items using powershell.

With one item it works.
    my snipet code below

Thanks

```
#When i run the script and having to pass one item it works but not with multiple items
function AddListAttachment([string] $itemid)
   {

    $CMRSItems = $list.Items | where {$_['ID'] -le $itemid}
    $CMRSItems | ForEach-Object {

    $id =  $_['RefID']
    $localFolderPath = "D:\CMRSDocs\" + $id

    $files = [IO.Directory]::GetFiles($localFolderPath)
        Write-Host $id



    ForEach($file in $files)
    {

    $bytes = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($file)
    #getting error here :but getting error :You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.

    $CMRSItems.Attachments.Add([System.IO.Path]::GetFileName($file), $bytes)

     #I can see each files of the $id here          #Write-Host $file
    }

   }
         Write-Host $file
    $CMRSItems.Update()
    $web.Dispose()

  }
```

Comment: The logic seems that when you pass an item id, you get all items less than or equal to id and then attach files to them. So what is the issue?

Comment: Nadeem when i do e.g equal to 1 it works fine but when i pass less than 4(which mean this will return 4 items it doesn't work).I can't get it to iterate though each id items(which is the folder path) and then attach the appropriate files in that folder.Cheers

Comment: Are you saying that if you change `$CMRSItems = $list.Items | where {$_['ID'] -le $itemid}` to `$CMRSItems = $list.Items | where {$_['ID'] -eq $itemid}` it works and not when you use `-le`

Comment: Yes Nadeem.Im trying to loop through each item in a list with id e.g 50.My folder structure has each folder with the id name which is 50 so e.g "D:\CMRSDocs\50"
Hope this helps.Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by loop through each item with id 50? There can only be one item with item id. Item id is unique.

Comment: Hi Nadeem, I was just giving an example.
Im passing the ids so its obviously iterating through the items.Basically im appending the ids to get a file directory.So for each directory get the files and attach

Comment: Hi Nadeem any ideas?

Comment: Figured it out. I added another function that basically added each attachment individually using GetItemById
Cheers.

Comment: Hey Share the solution, I'm needy for the same!