# Access to the path is denied PowerShell

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, powershell

I have to add the local files to list item as an attachment with **PowerShell**.
While reading the file I got an error "Access Denied" as below-

> **Exception calling "ReadAllBytes" with "1"
>   argument(s): "Access to the path 'D:\Projects\Test\List
>   Data\Attachments\3' is denied."

Code Snippet-

```
$filePath = "D:\Projects\Test\List Data\Attachments\" + $item.ID
$bytes = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($filePath)
$item.Attachments.Add([System.IO.Path]::GetFileName($filePath),$bytes)  
$item.Update()
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was missed to iterate the files in the folder, so it gives the error.

The below is the solution which I got from [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/94503/having-problems-attaching-files-to-multiple-items-using-powershell)

```
        $files = [IO.Directory]::GetFiles($filePath)
        ForEach($file in $files)
        {
        Write-Host "File Name = " $file
        $bytes = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($file)
        $row.Attachments.Add([System.IO.Path]::GetFileName($file), $bytes)
        }
        $row.Update()
```

Hope for the best!

Answer (score 4):

Make sure the current user have access to `D:\Projects\Test\List Data\Attachments\` by doing the following

- Right click in this folder >
- Select sharing with> provide the user that you have used to run PowerShell.
- Set `permission level` to can `Read and Write`.
- Try to run the script again, it should be working.

**Update**

I have noticed that you didn't pass the extension of your file , `$filePath = "D:\Projects\Test\List Data\Attachments\" + $item.ID` try to concatenate the extension like `$filePath = "D:\Projects\Test\List Data\Attachments\" + $item.ID +".the file extension"` , maybe this is the reason !

Comment: I have not used any user to run the powerShell.
Windows user Administrator have the full rights to Read and Write.

Comment: are you using SharePoint management shell to run this script ?

Comment: No, I am using Windows PowerShell ISE.

Comment: in my case, I tried to run SharePoint management shell via farm account and provide the farm account read and write to this folder

Comment: The user I am using have the full rights!

Comment: I have noticed that you didn't pass the extension of your file , $filePath = "D:\Projects\Test\List Data\Attachments\" + $item.ID try to concatenate the extension like $filePath = "D:\Projects\Test\List Data\Attachments\" + $item.ID +".the file extension" , maybe this is the reason !

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50586/discussion-between-ram-and-m-qassas).